# How to run Testcontainers with in-memory filesystem TMPFS set in Quarkus

Tags: java, spring-boot, kotlin, quarkus, testcontainers

I have the following issue.

In order to speed up the integration test pipeline I want to run `testcontainers` with `Quarkus` with `TMPFS` option set. This will force testcontainers to run the DB with a in-memory file system.

This can be easily done according to `testcontainers` website like this ...

> To pass this option to the container, add TC_TMPFS parameter to the URL as follows:
> jdbc:tc:postgresql:9.6.8:///databasename?TC_TMPFS=/testtmpfs:rw

Seems like problem solved. This is how it should work with `Spring Boot`

However, with `Quarkus` in their [docs](https://quarkus.io/guides/databases-dev-services) it says the following ...

> All services based on containers are ran using testcontainers. Even though extra URL properties can be set in your application.properties file, specific testcontainers properties such as TC_INITSCRIPT, TC_INITFUNCTION, TC_DAEMON, TC_TMPFS are not supported.

**And my question is:**

How can you work around this ? How can I run my testcontainer which will be mounted on TMPFS ?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can try to set the TMPFS using a `QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager` [guide](https://quarkus.io/guides/getting-started-testing#quarkus-test-resource).

Quarkus Kotlin example:

```kotlin
class DatabaseTestLifeCycleManager : QuarkusTestResourceLifecycleManager {
    private val postgresDockerImage = DockerImageName.parse("postgres:latest")

    override fun start(): MutableMap<String, String>? {
        val container = startPostgresContainer()

        return mutableMapOf(
            "quarkus.datasource.username" to container.username,
            "quarkus.datasource.password" to container.password,
            "quarkus.datasource.jdbc.url" to container.jdbcUrl
        )
    }

    private fun startPostgresContainer(): PostgreSQLContainer<out PostgreSQLContainer<*>> {
        val container = PostgreSQLContainer(postgresDockerImage)
            .withDatabaseName("dataBaseName")
            .withUsername("username")
            .withPassword("password")
            .withEnv(mapOf("PGDATA" to "/var/lib/postgresql/data"))
            .withTmpFs(mapOf("/var/lib/postgresql/data" to "rw"))
        container.start()
        return container
    }

    override fun stop() {
        // close container
    }
}
```

Comment: Yup, in the end, I went with `withTmpFs`. Thanks for posting it -- I didn't have the time to do it myself.

Comment: @Andreas Did you test that it works or this is just a suggestion ?

Comment: Tested and working @ArthurKlezovich
Needed to add the line `.withEnv(mapOf("PGDATA" to "/var/lib/postgresql/data"))` to work properly.

Answer (score 1):

You could try using the following configuration:

```
quarkus.datasource.url=jdbc:tc:postgresql:9.6.8:///databasename?TC_TMPFS=/testtmpfs:rw
```